# Offline Javadoc Server

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, offline

As not all our development machines have internet access, we want to cache the API docs of various libraries in our local network. I was thinking of a webapp that handles caching and listing the available Javadocs after someone uploads them (in jar format). Ideally, the source jars would be automatically pulled from our maven repository (artifactory).

I have not been successful in finding anything like this on google, so I'm trying my luck here.

**EDIT**

I have found a site that does exactly what I am looking for: http://www.jarvana.com The problem is that this site does not fulfill my #1 requirement - offline availability. So I rephrase my question to: Is there a webapp that works like jarvana but that can be deployed to a local server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what I'm looking for really doesn't exist, so I've rolled my own really simple webapp that serves JavaDocs from a local maven repository (transparently extracting jar files). It's far from perfect, but it works for my requirements. If anyone is interested, I shared it on github:

https://github.com/planbnet/JavaDoc-Browser

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `mvn site`?

Hm, I'd better add something more useful than that :-)

mvn site will build and deploy a bunch of site reports including the javadoc (assuming you configure that plugin).  Everytime your CI server builds the code from trunk/branch/tag/whereever, the latest Javadocs will be generated and stored on the file system (accessible via HTTP)!

There's even a cool report that ties the javadoc into the source code.

Comment: That would mean downloading the sources and building the Javadoc from scratch. So it would only work for libraries that use maven and are open source.

Comment: Just to clarify: For our own libraries, that's a great solution, but we want to provide the docs of third party libraries.

Comment: I think it is not necessarily to build javadocs from source. Download them to your local repository and create links to them in site.xml.

Comment: And assuming the 3rd party libs are in Maven central (or other repo), I believe you can dload their javadoc.jar and link to it as @AlexR states.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [wwwoffle](http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/wwwoffle/) a try. A caching proxy which enables to access sites while you're offline.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I already played with a recursive wget for fetching docs. All this stuff works, but it would be so much easier to just provide a jar file (or have that pulle from maven).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script some time ago to serve the javadoc from my local maven repo:

http://blog.robotninjas.org/2013/04/17/accessing-your-cached-javadoc-offline/

```
python javadoc.py
```

It's crude, but hitting `http://localhost:8080/m2` will list all of the projects in your local maven repository with downloaded docs.

You can download all the javadoc jars for a maven project with:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```